# Save list values in csv file with Python

Tags: python, list, csv, format, save

I have a Python simple list like this one:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

I want to save it in a csv file that looks like this:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
>   9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16

How can I do that? I tried:

```
np.savetxt('fname.csv', bbox_form, fmt='%d')
```

But I don't know how to write a new line only after 8 values.

Comment: What does `a = np.reshape(a, (-1, 8))`  do? If it doesn't throw errors, save that.

Comment: Do you have to do it exclusively using `numpy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
col_num=8
row_num=len(a)/col_num
b=np.reshape(a, [row_num,col_num])
d=[','.join(map(str,c)) for c in b]
np.savetxt('fname.csv', d, fmt='%s')
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Numpy will save each "row" in your array to a line. If you want to save it to multiple lines, then you'll need to reshape your array.

Have a look here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html